# Jaxb annotations to deserialize json data using Jackons

Tags: json, jaxb, jackson

I do have a simple json data and my pojo is annotated with jaxb annotations. I wanted to deserialize it WITHOUT using json annotations.

(It's must, please do NOT suggest to use both annotations on pojo).

Jackson confirms (that's what I understood) that it's possible through
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations

But when I ran the code, it does NOT provide the desired result.

Here is the pojo.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Simple_root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Simple {
    @XmlElement(name = "x")
    private String firstName;
    @XmlElement(name = "y")
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Below is the test class with two test methods using jackson ObjectMapper.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule;

public class XmlMapperTest {

    @Test
    public void jsonDeserialize_using_JaxbAnnotationIntrospector() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        jsonMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
        jsonMapper.getDeserializationConfig().with(introspector);
        jsonMapper.getSerializationConfig().with(introspector);

        Simple simple = jsonMapper.readValue("{\"Simple_root\": {\"x\": \"2\", \"y\": \"4\"}}", Simple.class);
        Assert.assertNotNull(simple.getFirstName());
        Assert.assertNotNull(simple.getLastName());
    }

    @Test
    public void jsonDeserialize_using_JaxbAnnotationModule() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        jsonMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        JaxbAnnotationModule jaxbModule = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
        jsonMapper.registerModule(jaxbModule);

        Simple simple = jsonMapper.readValue("{\"Simple_root\": {\"x\": \"2\", \"y\": \"4\"}}", Simple.class);
        Assert.assertNotNull(simple.getFirstName());
        Assert.assertNotNull(simple.getLastName());
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I know I am definitely missing something which I couldn't find out in a day and 2 hours before bedtime.

Comment: If you are going to add the root value in the JSON, you need to configure the property `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE`

Comment: No effect having UNWARP, the values [ simple.getFirstName() &simple.getLastName() ] are still NULL.

Comment: You set it on the ObjectMapper to true?